# Agora Java sample Code RTC Token not working

Tags: agora.io

[enter image description here][removed image]

I have used Java sample Code but I can't create a  call Using generated token. When I generated a token from the agora console I can Call. I tested it using this https://webdemo.agora.io/basicVideoCall/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Please update your question to include more information about how you are using the token that gets generated.

- Are you setting the user ID in the web demo?
- is there an error log in the console?

> Note: I removed the image because it contained private keys, I would recommend you reset your App Certificate to avoid any issues.

Once you update your question, I'll be happy to update the answer to be more specific to your issue.

For now, here are two open-source token servers that were built by the Agora DevRel team and I am sure they work (just add your credentials).

- [Node JS](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/Agora-Node-TokenServer)
- [GoLang](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/agora-token-service)